# How to monitor Azure PaaS services?

Tags: azure, storage, paas

Is there anyway we can get notified in case of Azure PaaS service is down? example Storage account or Load balancer etc?

Comment: https://status.azure.com/ , btw it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: And don't forget [Service Health](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/serviceIssues). You can even set [Health alerts](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/healthAlerts). "Azure Service Health notifies you about Azure service incidents and planned maintenance so you can take action to mitigate downtime. Configure customizable cloud alerts and use your personalized dashboard to analyze health issues, monitor the impact to your cloud resources, get guidance and support, and share details and updates."

Comment: Thanks, can we add specific service in the service health?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [rickvdbosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945525/rickvdbosch). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

- You can set [Health alerts](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Health/AzureHealthBrowseBlade/healthAlerts). "Azure Service Health notifies you about Azure service incidents and planned maintenance so you can take action to mitigate downtime. Configure customizable cloud alerts and use your personalized dashboard to analyze health issues, monitor the impact to your cloud resources, get guidance and support, and share details and updates."

> can we add specific service in the service health?

- In [Service Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/service-health-overview), choose the **Potential impact** tab to see the specific list of resources you own that might be impacted by the issue. You can download a CSV list of these resources to share with your team.

  [image]